# Sum list of datetime.time

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a list of datetime.time

```
[ datetime.time(2, 0), datetime.time(1, 0), datetime.time(1, 0), ...]
```

How can I do the sum of those values ? I tried to simply to

```
sum(mylist)
```

but I have an error "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.time'"

Comment: What is a sum of `datetime.time` instances supposed to give anyway?? Perhaps you want to use `datetime.timedelta` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `start=…` parameter, such that it does not start with `0`, but with a timedelta` with a duration that is zero.

Furthermore you can not add up two `time` items, since it makes no sense to add two o'clock and five o'clock. You should work with a timedelta:

```
from datetime import timedelta

data = [timedelta(hours=2), timedelta(hours=1), timedelta(hours=1)]
```

and then sum these up with:

```
sumd = sum(data, start=timedelta())
```

Comment: this is awesome, thanks Willem! never knew `sum` took another arg. for future visitors, this feature is available starting in Python 3.8 https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
import datetime as dt
t1 = dt.datetime.strptime('12:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
t2 = dt.datetime.strptime('02:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
time_zero = dt.datetime.strptime('00:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
print((t1 - time_zero + t2).time())
```